# R-Shiny - Change file by SelectInput and re-run code

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am working on a shiny app. I am sorry if I am unclear, but I am at the very beginning with shiny.

Basically, I have a long list of functions that are sourced into the shiny app before starting the server and the ui.
All these functions rely on a single database which is imported in the source file through an readRDS call.

```
source("calculations.R")

dash <- shinyApp(
   server = function(input, output) {
     
     
    output$element1 <- renderText({db1$var1[[1]]})
    ...
      },
      
      ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
        dashboardPage(
        options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
        header = dashboardHeader(title="Title"),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE),
        body = dashboardBody(
          fluidRow(
            column(width=8, box(width=12, title="Hello", valueBox(width=6, color="yellow", textOutput("element1")))
       ... 
       ),
       ),
        controlbar = dashboardControlbar(selectInput(inputId='selectfile','Select File',choice = list.files('folder/'))),
        title = "DashboardPage"
      )))
    )
    
    dash
```

The structure of the source file is pretty much the following:

```
db1 <- readRDS("folder/file1.rds")
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to let the user select another file from the folder (let's say, `file2.rds`) through the `selectInput` in the dashboard.
This should be following by:

1. replacing the old `db1` with the new one (i.e., `db1 <- readRDS("folder/file2.rds")`)
2. update all the following code in the `calculations.R` file (I've created a `calculations2.R` file, which is a copy of `calculations.R`, but without the first line of code which read the file and put into the `db1` object, as it would overwrite the new file)
3. update the `output` variables in the server
4. update the data in the UI.

I've tried several solution. Currently I am stuck with the following (in which `calculations2.R` contains the same code of `calculations.R`, without the `db1 <- readRDS("folder/file1.rds")` call at the beginning of the file):

```
   shinyApp(
   server = function(input, output) {
     
    db1 <- reactive({readRDS(file.path("folder",input$selectfile))})
    observeEvents(input$selectfile, {source("calculations2.R")}) 
    output$element1 <- renderText({db1$var1[[1]]})
    ...
      },
```

However, everytime I select another file from the `selectInput`, it get me an error from the functions in the `calculations2.R`, as if `db1` was not appropriately loaded.

Comment: Try to use `fileInput` to select the data from your folder.  Then modify your calculations.R to use the input dataframe.  You don't need calculations2.R.

Comment: @YBS is `fileInput` used to upload a file, isn't it? I don't need the user to upload a file, I just need the user (which is me) to select a file which is already existent.

Comment: If your filenames are known (fixed), then you can use that in `selectInput`.

Comment: @YBS Thanks, indeed they are. The problem is that I am not able to refresh the content when the selectInput is activated - it seems that the output$[whatever] does not respond to the update of the file…

Comment: Please read-up on reactive programming, as `renderText({db1$var1[[1]]})` is not reactive.